# No parameterless constructor defined for this object in automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

#### Question

I have the following value resolver:

```
public class StudentResolver : IValueResolver<Lesson, LessonResponse, UserResponse>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public StudentResolver(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    
    public UserResponse Resolve(
        Lesson lesson, 
        LessonResponse response, 
        UserResponse member, 
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var user = _dbContext.Users
            .Where(x => x.Id == lesson.StudentId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
            return null;
        var result = Mapper.Map<UserResponse>(user); // this line triggers a "no parameterless constructor", why?
        return result;
    }
}
```

This resolver tries to fetch the `Student` attribute for this model:

```
public class LessonResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public UserResponse Student { get; set; }
}
```

But on the line:

```
var result = Mapper.Map<UserResponse>(user);
```

I get:

> {System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)   at AutoMapper.MappingOperationOptions`2.CreateInstanceT}

The only type in that expression that should be created is `UserResponse` which is defined as follows:

```
public class UserResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string X { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsClient { get; set; }
    public bool IsInstructor { get; set; }
}
```

But it is constructible, so what am I doing wrong?

---

#### Extra

The mapping profile is the following:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile 
{
    public MappingProfile() {
        CreateMap<Lesson, LessonResponse>()                
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Student,
                opts => opts.ResolveUsing<StudentResolver>());

    }
}
```

And the mapping for the user is:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile 
{
    public MappingProfile() {
        CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserResponse>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.FullName, 
                opts => opts.MapFrom(
                    origin => origin.FirstName + " " + origin.LastName))
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.IsAdmin,
                opts => opts.ResolveUsing<IsAdminResolver>())
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.IsInstructor,
                opts => opts.ResolveUsing<IsInstructorResolver>())
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.IsClient,
                opts => opts.ResolveUsing<IsClientResolver>());
    }
}
```

The boolean resolvers are all similar to:

```
public class IsAdminResolver : IValueResolver<ApplicationUser, UserResponse, bool>
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public IsAdminResolver(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    
    public bool Resolve(ApplicationUser user, UserResponse response, bool member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your mapping configuration for the related objects?

Comment: @12seconds Added.

Comment: What about the mapping between `UserResponse` and `User`? Is it just the standard `MapFrom`?

Comment: @12seconds No, sorry. Added the mapping for that too.

Comment: Did you resolve you problem ?

Comment: @neustart47 No. I stopped working with Automapper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sorry for long response time since yesterday was exhausted after work.

I was able to replicate your issue. You have 2 options:

1st Option Resolve your `StudentResolver` with your `DbContext`:

```
CreateMap<Lesson, LessonResponse>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Student,
                opts => opts.ResolveUsing(new StudentResolver(ApplicationDbContext.Create())));
```

2nd Option, configure your mapper configuration `ConstructServicesUsing`. In my case I was using Simple Injector to test things out.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => container.GetInstance(typeof(StudentResolver)));
            cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
        });
```

For my testing, I was getting an error thrown `var lessonResponse = Mapper.Map<LessonResponse>(lesson);`

So if your is thrown for `Mapper.Map<UserResponse>(user);` you may have to ConstructService for `IsAdminResolver`, `IsInstructorResolver` and `IsClientResolver`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The first option is probably not feasible because `ApplicationDbContext` is managed by ASP.NET core's dependency injection mechanism. Trying to make it automatically inject a db context into a `Profile` led to similar errors. I'm not sure where the second option should be described. Should I put that initialization in the `Profile` constructor?

Comment: @Shoe the `Mapper.Initialize` I usually initialise my profiles in the Startup. How did you initialise yours?

Comment: @Shoe take a look at this, might help. 3rd snippet https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/20/integrating-automapper-with-asp-net-core-di/

Comment: What is `container` here?

Comment: @Zenexer, that would be dependent on what Dependency Injection you are using, in answer above is `SimpleInjector`

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say this question is using the built-in DI in ASP.NET Core, which is why @Shoe was never able to get it to work.  Is there a way to use AutoMapper in this context without breaking the DI paradigm?

Comment: @Zenexer, the link to jimmybogard on my comment above, shows you an example with dotnet core.

Comment: @penleychan That seems like it's reinventing the wheel when [this exists](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/), plus it's extremely complicated and defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yah I agree, however I don't have a solution for what you are looking for. I don't use automapper anymore in my projects.

Comment: Looks like my problem was slightly different: I was making [this mistake](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/18).  Dropping a link to that issue here in case anyone else runs into it.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem because of my inattention. I generated it with Visual Studio quick tip default constructor for the class inherited from `Profile` which was `protected` instead of `public`. I hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else does the same thing I did, here's what my problem was:

```
public sealed class MyProfile : Profile
{
    MyProfile()
    {
        // Configuration
    }
}
```

As you can see, I forgot to mark the constructor as `public`. Once I marked it public everything worked fine.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Mine was labelled protected for some reason. Don't know whether I mistyped it or it was some form of autocompletion issue. I actually ignored this solution rejecting it to be even possible to later on find that this was indeed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and it turned out that this line of code should have been the last line of code in our startup

`services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());`

Furthermore, when loading autofac modules, we moved our local registrations to the last lines so they overwrite the ones comming from nuget packages.

Pleased note that removing a constructor is not the solution so try to fix your dependency injection issues as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well in `AutoMapper` `11.0.1` and `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` 11.0.0.

It seems that if assembly scanning is enabled for the assembly that contains the `Profile` derived class that does not have a No-Args constructor, that AutoMapper tries to instantiate it even with an explicit registration.  What worked for me is to disable the type scanning for that repository by providing an empty array to match the correct overload.  Either an empty array of `Type` or `Assembly` will work.

Assuming your dependency `ApplicationDbContext` is available via .NET core dependency injection then you can use the overload on the `IServiceCollection` extension methods in `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` that accepts an `Action<IServiceProvider,AutoMapper.IMapperConfigurationExpression>` and `params Type[]` or `params Assembly[]` arguments to instantiate your profile class when the DI container is built.

The downside of this is because scanning needs to be disabled, all profile classes in that assembly need to now be explicitly registered, including no-arg ones.  This seems like a bug to me as I would expect the explicit instantiation to be favored for a type over the generic scanning, but there might be a timing component to this in the implementation that would make that difficult to achieve.

```
        return services.AddAutoMapper((serviceProvider, mapperConfiguration) =>
            {
                mapperConfiguration.AddProfile(new MappingProfile(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            },
            Array.Empty<Type>()
        );
```

Comment: Very helpful answer. The `serviceProvider` should be able to resolve any DI that the `AutoMapper` class needs in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Startup - ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAutoMapper(x=> x.AddProfile(new
MappingProfile(dependencyAlredyDefinedBefore) ));
```

MappingProfile class

```
DependencyClass readonly dependency;

//Constructor as usual
public MappingProfile(DependencyClass dependency)
{
    this.dependency = dependency;
    //Configure maps using dependency...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have multiple class libraries and I had AutoMapperProfile file in one of them. I moved it to my startup project and it worked.
another solution is to enable automapper in startup like this :

```
            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

then your profile can be anywhere inside your project.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had the following mapper:

```
public class Mapper : Profile
{
   public Mapper(IConfiguration configuration)
   {

   }
}
```

The fix was removing configuration parameter from the constructor (and thus making it parameterless constructor).

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to use Mapster instead AutoMapper , Because of Mapster many benefits :)

But the answer to your question :

add a constructor with out parameter to class witch inherit from profile
if you want to have constructor with parameter , no problem , but earlier , add constructor with out parameter in class

like this :

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {

    }
    public MappingProfile(AnyParameter)
    {
        //do config with input parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem with my answer?