# Automapper inject DbContext in the Profile class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have the following mapping profile

```
public class DomainProfile : Profile
{
    private FootballPredictionsContext m_Context;

    public DomainProfile(FootballPredictionsContext context)
    {
        m_Context = context;
    }

    public DomainProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TipModel, Tip>()
            .ForMember(tip => tip.BetType, m => m.MapFrom(x => m_Context.BetTypes.First(y => y.Name == x.BetType)))
            .ForMember(tip => tip.BetCategory, m => m.MapFrom(x => m_Context.BetCategories.First(y => y.Name == x.BetCategory)))
            .ForMember(tip => tip.Sport, m => m.MapFrom(x => m_Context.Sports.First(y => y.Name == x.Sport)))
            .ForMember(tip => tip.Tipster, m => m.MapFrom(model => m_Context.Tipsters.First(y => y.Username == model.Tipster)));
    }
}
```

As you can see, some of the mappings are using the `DbContext`, so I have to somehow inject it in the `DomainProfile`

In the Startup class I am initializing the Automapper normally

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IUnificator), typeof(Unificator));
            services.AddDbContext<FootballPredictionsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));
            services.AddDbContext<UnificationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));

            services.AddSingleton(provider => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile(new UserProfile(provider.GetService<IUserManager>()));
                }).CreateMapper());
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901316/1271230) solution, but I am receiving `'Cannot resolve scoped service 'FootballPredictions.DAL.FootballPredictionsContext' from root provider.'`

Comment: I've come across a similar problem recently and it was down to the fact that I was trying to inject a service into a service with a longer lifetime (e.g. transient and scoped). What lifetime is associated with the DomainProfile class? Have you tried changing that to Scoped or Transient to see if that helps?

Comment: Move your dependencies in resolvers or type converters. See [here](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html). Profiles are singletons.

Comment: @SimplyGed yes, this fixed the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've come across a similar problem recently and it was down to the fact that I was trying to inject a service into a service with a longer lifetime (e.g. transient and scoped). What lifetime is associated with the DomainProfile class? Have you tried changing that to Scoped or Transient to see if that helps?

As implemented by @DimitarTsonev:
So, changing the mapper scope to

```
services.AddScoped(provider => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new DomainProfile(provider.GetService<FootballPredictionsContext>()));
    }).CreateMapper());
```

fixed the issue

Comment: You can change your answer with the code provided in mine, and I will Accept it as answer.

Comment: When used in a ASP.NET web app, this massively impacts performance as the `.CreateMapper()` is basically called on every HTTP request and increased my service calls from 4-5ms to 20ms (4x slowdown). So use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've actually registered you context (`services.AddDbContext`, for example), the most likely cause of that exception is that you're registering AutoMapper *before* you're registering the context. Make sure your context is registered first, before you do something like `services.AddAutoMapper`.

Comment: If you look at the code provided, you will notice that they're registered in the correct order.