# What is the "instance" equivalent to using the "static" Mapper.Map inside CreateMap using AutoMapper 7.0.1?

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-7

I'm trying to upgrade to AutoMapper 7.0.1 which no longer uses static methods. I'm getting the following error:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate
>   configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a
>   container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the
>   static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or
>   UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the
>   appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

I think it's coming from profiles like this which I switched to not use static methods except it still uses the static `Mapper.Map<>()` in the lambda expression:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CredentialDetailDto, CredentialDetail>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Owners, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(y => 
                Mapper.Map<IList<OwnerDto>>(y.Owners)))
    }
}
```

How can I get an instance of the mapper to be used in place of the static `Mapper.Map` method?

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877379/how-inject-service-in-automapper-profile-class

Comment: Context.Mapper.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I'm not seeing any `Context` property on a Profile. What would the usage look like?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, your comment helped me find https://stackoverflow.com/a/43259537/64279. Would this be correct? `.ForMember(x => x.Owners, opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dst, arg3, context) => context.Mapper.Map<IList<OwnerDto>>(src.Owners)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Lucian's comment, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/43259537/64279. It seems that there are overloads which will pass you a context which has the instance of `IMapper`.

For example:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Owners, opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dst, arg3, context) => 
    context.Mapper.Map<IList<OwnerDto>>(src.Owners)))
```

There are overloads for the other methods as well, such as

```
.AfterMap((s, d, context) =>
```

And

```
.ConvertUsing((source, dst, context) =>
```

You just need to supply the right number of arguments in your lambda expression.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need this? That's what happens by default.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, if you mean what the code itself is doing, I didn't write it and don't know it's intention. It was written by people who probably didn't know what they were doing, but I can't be 100% sure. I'm just trying to upgrade it without breaking anything.

Comment: I see. Anyway, most likely it's not needed. Even if it is needed for some reason, it would look much better with MapFrom. That's what I was trying to say. But I see your point :)