# How to inject IConfiguration .net settings into Profile class?

Tags: c#, automapper

So I'm my appsettings I have some string array filters that I need to use within mapping.
How can I pass them to `MappingMethod` below? (sample below does not work as MyProfile can't have parameters)

```
public class MyProfile: Profile
{
    public MyProfile(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.X,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => MappingMethod(src.NestedSource, configuration.GetSection("settingsArray"))) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How inject service in AutoMapper profile class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877379/how-inject-service-in-automapper-profile-class)

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/141#issuecomment-1079914176

Comment: Does it mean I need to move my MappingMethod logic into CustomReolver and there I will be able to inject IConfiguration? @ESG

Comment: That's the idea.