# How to use services in a c# AutoMapper Action

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a profile set up:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAutoMapper((IMapperConfigurationExpression a) => {
        a.AddProfile<GeneralMappingProfile>();
    });
```

Here is the Profile:

```
public class GeneralMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public GeneralMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .AfterMap<SourceToDestinationAction>()
            .ForAllMembers(x => x.Ignore());
    }
}
```

My Action looks like this:

```
public class SourceToDestinationAction : IMappingAction<Source, Destination>
{
    private readonly IACoolService coolService;

    public SourceToDestinationAction(IACoolService _coolService){
        coolService = _coolService;
    }

    public void Process(Source source, Destination destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.Title = coolService.MakeMultiLanguageValue(source.Title);
    }
}
```

I'd like to use it like this:

```
...(IMapper mapper){
    ...
    Destination destinationData = mapper.Map<Destination>(sourceData);
}
```

This doesn't work because the Action requires a parameterless constructor.

How do I go about having dependencies in my Actions?

System information:

- .Net6.0
- AutoMapper 12.0.1
- AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
- A Web App

Notes for moderation:

- Please note, this is not DI for a Profile, but rather an Action.

Context information:

- I am trying to test a mapping in a unit test:

  ```
  MapperConfiguration config = new (cfg =>
  {
      GeneralMappingProfile profile = new();
      cfg.AddProfile(profile);
  });
  mapper = config.CreateMapper();
  mapper.Map(item, content); // Throws error here as SourceToDestinationAction has no paramterless constructor
  ```

Error thrown:

> Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'SourceToDestinationAction '. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How inject service in AutoMapper profile class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877379/how-inject-service-in-automapper-profile-class)

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is how to inject into a profile class. I would like to inject into an Action class.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using AutoMapper, instead of injecting ` IMappingAction<Source, Destination>` directly into wherever you need to map? It seems you are only "using" Automapper to get this dependency and if you injected it directly, your DI would already take care of it.

Comment: I had assumed you can go through IMapper to use the Map<Source, Dest> function, but I will try to use IMappingAction<Source, Dest>.Process and see if the DI works at this point. Thanks. Bear with.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help too much because it requires ReqestContext when running against Process

Answer (score 1):

The problem boils down to the fact, that the service collection/service provider does not know how to build a `SourceToDestinationAction` instance, regardless of using AutoMapper or not. Even when all dependencies are added to the service collection, it still (apparently) doesn't know how to build the object, as seen in the following code:

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<IACoolService, MyCoolService>();
//services.AddSingleton<SourceToDestinationAction>();

IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
provider.GetRequiredService<SourceToDestinationAction>();
```

This will result in an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "No service for type '(namespace).SourceToDestinationAction' has been registered."

But when you use one of `AddSingleton()`/`AddScoped()`/`AddTransient()` to register the type to your service collection, it can resolve the type without problem.

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<IACoolService, MyCoolService>();
services.AddSingleton<SourceToDestinationAction>();

IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var act = provider.GetRequiredService<SourceToDestinationAction>();
Console.WriteLine(act); // prints "(namespace).SourceToDestinationAction"
```

After that AutoMapper will finally be able to resolve the type as well.

The solution is to (explicit) register your `SourceToDestinationAction` class in your service collection, at least with `AddTransient()`. In fact, when you use `AddAutoMapper()` with an assembly instance as argument like

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(GeneralMappingProfile).Assembly);
```

it will register all such actions for your automatically, as seen in the source code of [ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapperClasses](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/104a192407858fe3a54a8a937ca95a34fd7c6959/src/AutoMapper/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L85):

> ```
> var openTypes = new[]
> {
>     typeof(IValueResolver<,,>),
>     typeof(IMemberValueResolver<,,,>),
>     typeof(ITypeConverter<,>),
>     typeof(IValueConverter<,>),
>     typeof(IMappingAction<,>)
> };
> foreach (var type in assembliesToScan.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract &&
>              Array.Exists(openTypes, openType => type.GetGenericInterface(openType) != null))))
> {
>     // use try add to avoid double-registration
>     services.TryAddTransient(type);
> }
> ```

Maybe the service collection/service provider can be configured in such way, that it automatically falls back to `transient` when the type isn't registered.

Comment: Obviously the main use case is to simply pass the needed assemblies and let the extension handle everything. That other stuff you can do, that's just extra flexibility :)

Comment: The issue appears to stem from the framework not being compatible with Actions that have parameters in the constructor. I will, however investigate as soon as I get time. I have migrated to my own separate classes that use normal DI to mitigate the problem while I work within deadlines. Thank you for this information.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 You can simply register your action with something like `services.AddSingleton<SourceToDestinationAction>();` and it should be able to create the instance of type `SourceToDestinationAction`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what versions you are using, but the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html) says you indeed *can* do this. This quote looks exactly like what you want to do:

> **Asp.Net Core and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection**

> If you are using Asp.Net Core and the AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection package, this is also a good way of using Dependency Injection. You can’t inject dependencies into Profile classes, but you can do it in IMappingAction implementations.

> The following example shows how to connect an IMappingAction accessing the current HttpContext to a Profile after map action, leveraging Dependency Injection:

```
public class SetTraceIdentifierAction : IMappingAction<SomeModel, SomeOtherModel>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SetTraceIdentifierAction(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    public void Process(SomeModel source, SomeOtherModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.TraceIdentifier = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    }
}

public class SomeProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SomeModel, SomeOtherModel>()
            .AfterMap<SetTraceIdentifierAction>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using AutoMapper 12.0.1 and .Net6.0. When I do this, I get "Action requires a parameterless constructor."

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 I have the same problem.. following the documentation exactly. The only difference is I am on net 7